# Output of 'watch' command as a list

Tags: watch

I want to do some simple computation of the number of lines per minute added to a log file. I also want to store the count for each second.

What I need is the output of the following command as a list which will be updated every second:

```
watch -n1 'wc -l my.log'
```

How can I output the 'update' of the 'watch' command as a list?

Answer (score 51):

You can use the `-t` switch to `watch` which causes it not to print header. However, that will still clear the screen so you might be better off with a simple shell loop:

```
while sleep 1; do
    wc -l my.log
done
```

One of the advantages is, that you can easily add other commands (e.g. `date`) and/or pipe the output through `sed` to reformat it. By the way, if you swap `sleep 1` with `wc` in the loop, it will automatically terminate on errors.

Comment: However note that it will not do it exactly every second (with zsh or ksh93, you could adjust the sleeping time so as to account for the drift incurred by running the commands in the loop, though)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas neither will it with `wait` - just try `watch -n 1 "sleep 5"`.

Comment: Indeed (I've checked both procps and busybox implementations). I thought that was the only thing `watch` was useful for, but it doesn't give you even that so your solution is as good as a watch based one, but neither answers the _"rate at which a log file grows"_ question with great accuracy.

Comment: Well, if *lines per minute* are the ultimate goal, then sampling it once every 10 seconds is more than enough imho - so the overhead is not that terrible (unless the file grows really big, of course). And actually from within the loop, one can print timing information (even both before and after the command finishes if necessary), and then the accuracy can get better (orders of magnitude) even for bigger files.

Comment: @peterph `watch` has a `-p` option that will do that right, if at all possible (obviously, you can't do a command that takes 5 seconds every 1 second, if you're not allowed multiple simultaneous). I know, I wrote it :-P

Comment: @derobert you mean `watch` from procps-ng? For the "canonical" one from the procps definitely doesn't have this option.

Comment: @peterph Yeah, I sent it to Debian in https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=183486 and Debian is using procps-ng. AFAIK, original procps upstream is unmaintained.

Comment: @derobert oh. Well, a quick glance at the procps CVS reveals how active the codebase has been in the last decade or so. I guess that's why it got forked into procps-ng (including your patch).

Comment: Another benefit of this approach is that `watch` only supports intervals down to 0.1 seconds, while [`sleep` supports "floating point numbers"](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sleep-invocation.html) as intervals (e.g. `sleep 0.0001` works just fine).

Answer (score 14):

An old question, but I just found a very easy answer:

```
watch -n1 'wc -l my.log | tee -a statistics.log'
```

This will execute your `wc` each second, add its output to the statistics.log file, and also show it on the screen.
So, you'll end up with a file filled with numbers, representing the successive number of lines of `my.log`.

Comment: Please note that this command is `watch "($MYCMD | tee -a $MYLOG)"`, not `watch "($MYCMD)" | tee -a $MYLOG`. If you got this wrong like I did, the output is going to be very very confusing.

Another thing to note here is that this command does not add the timestamp of each command's execution by default, so the answer with the loop might still work better for you.

Comment: Yes, quotes were meaningful in my answer, as well as they are in computer science  ;)

Answer (score 5):

You could create a script that does it for you. I called mine `keep` (like, keep doing it) and put it on the `bin` path.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Repeating command $* every second"
while sleep 1; do
    "$@"
done
```

Comment: You should use `"$@"` to execute the command (arguments) instead of unquoted `$*`. This way you'll have the shell keep quoted arguments, etc. as the user would expect them. FTFY.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
tail -f file.log | pv -rl > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
watch -n1 'wc -l my.log >> statistics.log'
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question when I was trying to get better/logged output from `du -sh $data_path`. I used the "while command, do sleep" pattern found here, but used some complex AWK to give the output I wanted.

```
while du -sh $data_path; do sleep 1; done | awk '
$1 != size {
    size=$1;
    path=$2;
    time=systime();
    seconds=time-prevtime;
    if(seconds < 1000000000){
        seconds=seconds" seconds"
    }else{
        seconds=""
    }
    print size, path, strftime("%m/%d/%Y@%H:%M:%S", time), seconds; 
    prevtime=time
}'
```

I actually did this as a oneliner, which is why there are semicolons. But to make it readable, I broke it out. The output looks like:

```
502G /var/lib/cassandra/dump/ 05/22/2018@04:46:17
503G /var/lib/cassandra/dump/ 05/22/2018@04:46:59 42 seconds
504G /var/lib/cassandra/dump/ 05/22/2018@04:47:57 58 seconds
505G /var/lib/cassandra/dump/ 05/22/2018@04:48:55 58 seconds
506G /var/lib/cassandra/dump/ 05/22/2018@04:49:53 58 seconds
507G /var/lib/cassandra/dump/ 05/22/2018@04:50:50 57 seconds
508G /var/lib/cassandra/dump/ 05/22/2018@04:51:46 56 seconds
509G /var/lib/cassandra/dump/ 05/22/2018@04:52:44 58 seconds
510G /var/lib/cassandra/dump/ 05/22/2018@04:53:41 57 seconds
```