# How to display the time every one minute using linux command?

Tags: linux

I used the following linux command to display the time `date +%T`. It displays the current time.

If I want to display the time every one minute which Linux command should I use?

Expected Result:

```
15:44:26
15:45:26
15:46:26
```

Comment: See also [Output of 'watch' command as a list](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56093)

Comment: Try this : `tm() { date +%T; sleep 1; tm; };tm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific unix command for this, but this be handled by a bit of shell script.

With `bash` (the standard shell provided with most Linux distro):

```
while [ 1 ]; do date "+%T"; sleep 60; done
```

Comment: With a small tweak you can remove the scrolling with `while [ 1 ]; do echo -en \`date "+%T"\`"\r"; sleep 60; done`