# Watch as list doesn’t work

Tags: shell

I tried [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56095/28856) to simulate a `watch` without `clear`:

```
while sleep 1; do ps -ef | grep convert | grep -v grep done
```

It leaves me with a greater-than symbol and the cursor next to it, nothing happens. Variants I tried that don’t work either:

```
while sleep 1; do ps -ef \| grep convert \| grep -v grep done
while sleep 1; do 'ps -ef | grep convert | grep -v grep' done
```

Why I want to do this: I want the results to be printed to standard output one below the next, and I do not want the line to be truncated to the window size.

Comment: The `;` before the `done` is missing, so the command is not finished and you get the `>` prompt

Comment: Btw, a trick to avoid that double filtering of `ps` is to use a superfluous regular expression like `grep conver[t]`: This will match your desired line, but not the `grep` line itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon. The correct command is:

```
while sleep 1; do ps -ef | grep convert | grep -v grep; done
```

On a multi-line command, this would be

```
while sleep 1
do 
   ps -ef | grep convert | grep -v grep
done
```